# java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out in Android

Tags: android, httpclient, connection-timeout, socketexception

I am calling Http Post request using HTTP client in a loop. After a few requests, I am getting java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out.
I have tried increasing the timeout in setConnectionTimeout() and setSoTimeout() but still the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

The Timeout contains:

```
ConnectionTimeout.
ReadTimeout.
WriteTimeout.
Exception.
```

check it what happened in it.

hope to help you.

Comment: ConnectionTimeout is happenning